# Windows 10 pro 1607 14393.10 has ssh server built-in?

Tags: windows-10, ssh, windows-10-v1607

I see SSH Server Broker and SSH Server Proxy services running and can connect to the machine from LAN and WAN.
I am not able to login with administrator account nor I was able to find any information about how it needs to be configured.

Anyone got any information?

Comment: I don't understand. Why down vote?

Comment: I have two 1607 machines, I see the SSH services only on the one which has `Bash on Ubuntu on Windows` installed. I can connect and are able to login as an admin, but only builtin cmd commands work. I have no idea yet what it is used for.